# undefined method with time_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, time-select

I am trying to use a time select with locals passed to the partial, but I am getting the following error

```
undefined method `open_time' for #<Merchant:0x007fb41fd0aa90>
```

Partial Call

```
= form_for @merchant, :url => admin_merchant_path(@merchant) do |form|
      #account-panel.mdl-tabs__panel
        = render :partial => 'venue', :locals => {:address_fields => form}
        = render :partial => 'hours', :locals => {:hour_fields => form}
```

Rendered Partial

```
.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--12-col
  /h3.mdl-typography--display-1.teal-heading= t('.trading_hours_title')
  - (0..6).each do |i|
    li.mdl-list__item.mdl-list__item--two-line
      span.mdl-list__item-primary-content
        = Date::DAYNAMES[i]
        span.mdl-list__item-sub-title
        = hour_fields.time_select :open_time, {:minute_step => 30, :ampm => true}
```

Merchant Model

```
has_many :trading_hours, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trading_hours
```

Trading Hour Model

```
belongs_to :merchant
```

Comment: Do you have `open_time` column in `Merchants` table ?

Comment: It will not work as currently you are calling `open_time ` on merchant instead of trading_hours, you should use fields_for to work with associated model.

Comment: @sawangupta can you explain a bit more on how I would use fields_for in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this(starting from the last line of your mentioned code):

```
<%= hour_fields.fields_for :trading_hours do |trading_field| %>
   <%= trading_field.time_select :open_time, {:minute_step => 30, :ampm => true} %>
<% end %>
```

And in Merchants controller action build `trading_hours` if you don't have any `trading_hour`:

```
@merchant.trading_hours.build
```

PS: This is is ERB(I know only this :) )

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned accepts_nested_attributes_for :trading_hours
If you have open_time column in your trading hours model the following code may help:

If you use simple_form in your app

```
= hour_fields.simple_fields_for :trading_hours do |nest_form|
  = nest_form.open_time
```